# Android AutoCompleteTextView display the chosen one

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have problem with my AutoCompleteTextView,

[image]

When I choose one of the suggestion,

[image]

It should show the Product Name (Junk Food or Western Food).
Anyone please help me to solve this. Below is Adapter & Filter Class.

**Filter Class**
    public class ProductFilter extends Filter {
        AdapterProductAutoComplete adapterProductAutoComplete;
        List originalList;
        List filteredList;

```
    public ProductFilter (AdapterProductAutoComplete adapterProductAutoComplete, List<Product>
            originalList){
        super();
        this.adapterProductAutoComplete = adapterProductAutoComplete;
        this.originalList = originalList;
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter.FilterResults performFiltering (CharSequence constraint){
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);
        }else{
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            for (final Product product : originalList){
                if(product.getProductName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern) || Integer
                        .toString(product.getProductId()).toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    filteredList.add(product);
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        adapterProductAutoComplete.filteredProducts.clear();
        adapterProductAutoComplete.filteredProducts.addAll((List) results.values);
        adapterProductAutoComplete.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class AdapterProductAutoComplete extends ArrayAdapter<Product>{
    private final List<Product> products;
    public List<Product> filteredProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    public AdapterProductAutoComplete(Context context, List<Product> products){
        super(context, 0, products);
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return filteredProducts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter(){
        return new ProductFilter(this, products);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        Product product = filteredProducts.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_actproduct, parent, false);
        TextView tvCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.actproduct_productcode);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.actproduct_productname);

        tvCode.setText(Integer.toString(product.getProductId()));
        tvName.setText(product.getProductName());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `toString()` method in your `Product` class because `AutoCompleteTextView` takes value from `toString()`. Add this code to your `Product` class:-

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return getProductName();
}
```

The default implementation of toString() method in Object class is this:-

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

it is what you are getting now.

Comment: i counter a new problem, it return suggestion item position instead of the correct ID. let say it return 5 suggestion, i choose the first one, but it will display in the field the first in a arraylist, not the one i am choosing. Do you understand?

Comment: use `getItemAtPosition()` method. Code:-  autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
selectedProduct=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            }
        });

Comment: please refer image in this link [link](http://imgur.com/a/SCg87) . the getItemAtPosition() still return wrong data.

Comment: @user2412351 please check complete example at this page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/5300/autocompletetextview#t=201612150705406934951). May be this helps you.